# jQuery get and set value in css attribute

Tags: jquery, css

this is my simple code:

```js
var qibla = $(".qd .wpb_wrapper").text();
        $('#qdir img').css('transform', 'rotate(' +qibla +'deg)');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html qd">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    218.4
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-image us_custom_9c0cfcca align_center" id="qdir"><div class="w-image-h"><img width="300" height="300" src="https://s20.picofile.com/d/8447362450/a60ba95e-4386-462e-8f26-10d69847adbf/download_1.svg" class="attachment-medium size-medium" alt="" loading="lazy"></div></div></div>
```

I want to get text value from "qd" element, that is 218.4

ad then set it into "#qdir" as css rotation attribute.
but not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `qibla` variable has additional space and enter character at the beginning and the end. Just use `trim()` function to remove them.

More information: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

```js
var qibla = $(".qd .wpb_wrapper").text().trim();
$('#qdir img').css('transform', 'rotate(' +qibla +'deg)');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html qd">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    218.4
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-image us_custom_9c0cfcca align_center" id="qdir"><div class="w-image-h"><img width="300" height="300" src="https://s20.picofile.com/d/8447362450/a60ba95e-4386-462e-8f26-10d69847adbf/download_1.svg" class="attachment-medium size-medium" alt="" loading="lazy"></div></div></div>
```